# yii2 advanced 2.06 createAbsoluteUrl

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm using the createAbsoluteUrl method of urlManager in order to generate a URL to view an instance of my message model by message ID.

```
Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(['/message/view', 'id'=>$model->id, '#' => $model->id])
```

This generates-
http://localhost/advancedyii2/frontend/web/index.php?r=message#

However, I require-
http://localhost/advancedyii2/frontend/web/index.php?r=message%2Fview&id=1

Can you identify the problem?

thanks,
pf

Comment: show you config/main.php  components urlManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need write your rule for your url in :
URL Manager Rules Configuration in web.php

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [               
        'showScriptName' => false,  // Disable index.php
        'enablePrettyUrl' => false, // Disable r= routes
        'enableStrictParsing' => true,
        'rules' => array(
                'mycategory/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                //Rules with Server Names
                'http://admin.domain.com/login' => 'admin/user/login',
                'http://www.domain.com/login' => 'site/login',
                'http://<country:\w+>.domain.com/profile' => 'user/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>-<slug:[A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+>' => '<controller>/view',
            ),
    ],
],
```

you can customize your url whatever way you need.
[More information](http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/url-manager-in-yiiframework-2-0/)